# Find the missing digit in the number 23104*791

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Find the missing digit in the number $23104*791$ if
>
> (i) it is divisible by $11$,
>
> (ii) it is divisible by $13$,
>
> (iii) it is divisible by $63$.

(i) $23104*791=231 (990+10)^2+4*(990+10)+11\times 72-1 \implies 11|4*0-1 \implies 11|400+*0-1 \implies 11|3+*0 \implies 11|*3 \implies *=3$

(ii) & (iii) Unable to adjust. Please help me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second, since we have 
$$10^3\equiv (-3)^3\equiv -27\equiv -1\pmod{13},$$
we have
$$(231)\cdot (10^3)^2+(40+*)\cdot 10^3+791\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$
$$\Rightarrow 10\cdot 1+(1+*)\cdot (-1)+11\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$
$$\Rightarrow *\equiv 10-1+11\equiv 7\pmod{13}$$
Hence, we have $*=\color{red}{7}$. (This is sufficient.)

For the third, it is divisible by $9$, so we have
$$2+3+1+0+4+*+7+9+1\equiv 0\pmod 9\Rightarrow *\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$
Also, it is divisible by $7$. Since we have 
$$10^3\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\equiv -1\pmod{7},$$
we have
$$(231)\cdot (10^3)^2+(40+*)\cdot 10^3+791\equiv 0\pmod{7}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0+(5+*)\cdot (-1)+0\equiv 0\pmod 7$$
$$\Rightarrow *\equiv 2\pmod 7$$
Hence, we have $*=\color{red}{9}$. (This is sufficient.)

Comment: $$23104*791=(231)\cdot (10^3)^2+(40+*)\cdot 10^3+791$$ Is this ok, see 04* not 40*

Comment: @user1942348: Yes, it is OK because $4*791=4\times 10^4+*\times 10^3+791=(4\times 10+*)\times 10^3+791$.

Comment: Yes, you r right, thanks a lot.

Comment: Would you please state the theorem responsible for the reduction of the step $$(231)\cdot (10^3)^2+(40+*)\cdot 10^3+791\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$
$$\Rightarrow 10\cdot 1+(1+*)\cdot (-1)+11\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$

Comment: Also please explain the reduction $$10\cdot 1+(1+*)\cdot (-1)+11\equiv 0\pmod{13}$$
$$\Rightarrow *\equiv 10-1+11\equiv 7\pmod{13}$$

Comment: @user1942348: For the first, all I used is $231\equiv 10,(10^3)^2\equiv 1,40\equiv 1,10^3\equiv -1,791\equiv 11\pmod{13}$. You may want to look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

Comment: @user1942348: For the second comment, since we have $10-1-*+11\equiv 0\pmod{13}$, we have $*\equiv 10-1+11\equiv 20\equiv 7\pmod{13}$.

Comment: In your 2nd answer: $$2+3+1+0+4+*+7+9+1\equiv 0\pmod 9\Rightarrow *\equiv 0\pmod{9}$$ does $*\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ implies $*=9$ ? If it is, the remaining part is not required. Please suggest.

Comment: @user1942348: Note that $*\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ means that $*$ is divisible by $9$. So, all we can say is that $*$ has to be either $9$ or $0$. Thus, the remaining part is required. (Note that $*\equiv 2\pmod{7}$ means that $*$ has to be either $2$ or $9$.)

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. Then * for division by 11 may also be solved by your process. In my case I have not use congruence.